# executing multiple commands batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to build script to chose commands to run but then they should run in a specific order which was set at the beginning by user.  for example:

```
:MENU
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO 1
IF %M%==2 GOTO 2
IF %M%==3 GOTO 3
IF %M%==4 GOTO 4
IF %M%==5 GOTO 5

:1
GOTO MENU

:2
GOTO MENU

:3
GOTO MENU

:4
GOTO MENU

:5
EXIT
```

For example in this scenario when I am prompt to choose 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 I would like to execute command: 1, 2, 4 then display MENU. So I simply type 1, 2, 4 on the screen and then batch will execute it - Commands should follow order 1 then 2 then 4

The other example would be 1, 3, 2, 4 etc.

is this possible? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
:MENU
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 then press ENTER:


for %%C in (%M%) do (
 call :%%C
)
goto :MENU    

:1
GOTO :EOF

:2
GOTO :EOF

:3
GOTO :EOF

:4
GOTO :EOF

:5
EXIT
```

I'm not absolutely sure if this is what you looking for..

Comment: nope :), ok, example 1 User input: 1, 2, 3. Script executes command from 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Example 2: User input: 2, 1, 4, 1. Script executes command from 2, 1, 4 and again 1.

Comment: this will do the same if the input is `2,1,4,1<Enter>`

Comment: sorry, you are right! When 2,1,4,1 will finish I would like it to go back to the Menu function. But then the user choice could be different so I would like it to go back to Menu every time the combination of user option finished.

Comment: @MartinM - The code is just missing a GOTO MENU after the closure of the FOR loop.

Comment: +1 It will work well - I edited the code and added the `goto :menu` as @dbenham mentioned.